# How to add a scrollbar to a textview?

Tags: ios, textview, scrollbar, xamarin

iOS for a school project and I fill my UITextView dynamically with labels (with x and y positions). But since it has a lot of items the total length of the items is bigger than the iPhone screen height. I expected an automatic vertical scroll bar to appear but it doesn't, so users cannot go down and read the rest of the articles.

How can I add it?

Solution thanks to @elitalon:

```
scrollTextView.ContentSize = new SizeF(scrollTextView.Frame.Width, sizeH); // Works
```

instead of

```
scrollTextView.ContentSize.Height = sizeH; // Doesn't work
```

Comment: You will your text view with labels? Do you mean you add labels to a UIScrollView?

Comment: Could you give more details about your problem? A `UITextView` object automatically displays a scroll whenever the **text** entered does not fit within the frame. If you're adding anything else you need to calculate the height dynamically

Comment: I add UILabels dynamicly to the textview so it is using x and y coordinates to position the labels and set the height and width of the label. So how can I let the scroll appear in this situation? 0x7fffffff you will your < :) It's an UITextView

Comment: That's not how it works. If you want to use a UITextView, you add the label's text to the UITextView's `text` property, and if the text is larger than the text view's frame, scrolling will be enabled automatically. If you want to manually position UILabels on screen, you'll want to add them to a UIScrollView, and adjust it's `contentSize` property to enable scrolling.

Comment: 0x7fffffff could you maybe give me an example of the option with the UIScrollView as the UITextView is within a UIScrollView at the moment as I tryd that. But what calculation would I use for the contentSize? Also the UITextView has a contentSize item wouldn't I be able to use that or?

Comment: Where are you displaying the text of the articles? In labels or in the `UITextView` object?

Comment: @elitalon The UITextView is not used anymore as it's now directly added to the UIScrollView

Comment: Sounds like you should ditch `UITextView` and make a custom `UIScrollView` implementation...but I may misunderstand what's going on here.

Comment: @James already done that now the labels are added as subviews to the UIScrollView but yeah the height of the scrollview doesn't change in the code.

Comment: @elitalon Do you know a solution as to why the height stays at 432 instead of the sizeH then?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve exactly, but I think that the problem is a misuse of the `UITextView` class. As [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) documentation says:

> *The UITextView class implements the behavior for a scrollable, multiline text region"*

So ideally you should not add `UILabel` objects to a `UITextView`. Instead, I would create a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` for each article you want to display:

```
UILabel *article1Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label1Frame];
UITextView *article1Text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:text1Frame];

UILabel *article2Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label2Frame];
UITextView *article2Text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:text2Frame];

...
```

If you want your users to scroll and read all the articles you can add all these subviews to a `UIScrollView` object:

```
UIScrollView *articlesScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
[articlesScrollView addSubview:article1Label];
[articlesScrollView addSubview:article1Text];
[articlesScrollView addSubview:article2Label];
[articlesScrollView addSubview:article2Text];
```

Finally, you calculate the `UIScrollView` content size by adding all the heights of your subviews. For example:

```
CGFloat totalHeight = article1Text.frame.size.height + article2Text.frame.size.height;
articleScrollView.contentSize = {
  .width = articleScrollView.bounds.size.width,
  .height = totalHeight
};
```

Comment: elitalon I added it like the way you said (with xamarin so code is C#) : scrollTextView.ContentSize.Height = sizeH; where sizeH is a float of all label heights I don't see a need for a uitextview for each item and only use the labels with the UIScrollView called scrollTextView. (linked the variable to the scrollview on the storyboard). Now the scroll bar still doesn't appear in the iPhone Simulator? do you know why?

Comment: Post your source code then, because trying to solve your problem with so little information is kinda difficult

Comment: I'm trying this: `code`RectangleF rect = scrollTextView.Frame;
   rect.Size.Height = sizeH;
   scrollTextView.Frame = rect;
   Console.WriteLine(scrollTextView.Frame.Size.Height);`code` but notice something strange the height stays at 432 while sizeH = 770

Comment: I added it to the question as you can see the code is c# (xamarin) but yeah as I told in the comment up here the height stays at 432 instead of the 770 that sizeH returns.